# using GCP api php client v1 methods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-php-client

I'm still stuck on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58126932/problem-in-gcp-setiampolicy-api-reference-under-php-example) and I'm rephrasing it after a bit more exploration.

I cannot find code examples for using `google-api-php-client with v1 API` methods like `projects/setIamPolicy()` [On this example](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy)

The PHP example appears to be broken because `$service->projects` is undefined. The equivalent nodejs example "just works".

I've attempted to switch to the v1-master branch, but the same code is still incompatible. I've attempted some modifications to compensate for v2 authentication methods used in the example, but hit a dead end.

What is the proper way to use v1 methods via PHP?

EDIT
It looks like this simple composer file is my solution:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "google/apiclient-services": "0.50"
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick searching couldn't find nothing related in [google-api-php-client samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples) nor a iam folder in  [php-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/). I believe other languages like Go or Python have "more/better maintained" client libraries, check [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iam/api-client/access.py).

Comment: I also tried the nodejs examples, which work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing the [documentation instructions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy#examples), I came across the same error of undefined property $projects in $service.
It seems that the documentation examples for PHP Cloud Resource Manager API v1 are defining classes (like $service = new Google_Service_CloudResourceManager($client);) that are actually implemented in v2.

[v1 Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/107dc7d30fa9c6e5b75ce1200665e4fc3adfba6e/src/Google/Service/Cloudresourcemanager.php#L40) contains variables $organizations and $projects.

[v2 Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/CloudResourceManager.php) contains variables $folders and $operations.

In the documentation example, the script tries to access $projects, using the v2 Class, where $projects doesn’t exist, but $folders and $operations do.

[image]

By using a [version of google-api-php-client-services Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/releases/tag/v0.50), which includes the latest version n of v1, you can access $folders, $liens, $operations, $organizations, $projects but still use V2 Classes of google-api-php-client.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971562/how-to-create-project-in-google-console-cloud-platform-using-php-lib-programmati Please look at this issue, share your suggestion.