# How to create project in Google Console Cloud platform using PHP Lib programmatically?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-apis-explorer, google-iam

I am trying to create a project in the Google console cloud using the PHP client library.
I copied this sample code from https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create#php

**Steps taken/ Got the issue:**

1. This line " `$requestBody = new \Google_Service_CloudResourceManager_Project();` ".

   **Throwing error** : 'Class Google_Service_CloudResourceManager_Project not found'.

   Then I checked in the "[Try this API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh4Cy.png)" menu, we can pass the JSON to API with Google API Explorer. I tested with Google API Explorer and the results are working fine. ([See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh4Cy.png))
2. Commenting this line "`$requestBody = new \Google_Service_CloudResourceManager_Project();`"
   and trying to pass the json required to create method ( as i have checked in "[Try this API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh4Cy.png)" menu).

   **Throwing error** :  Call to a member function `create()` on null at this line "`$response = $service->projects->create($requestBody);`".

**My Google OAuth script is working fine, only issue with this project create script**

**PHP Script:**

```
$client = new \Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName('Google-CloudResourceManagerSample/0.1');
//$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');

$service = new \Google_Service_CloudResourceManager($client);

// TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:

//$requestBody = new \Google_Service_CloudResourceManager_Project();

$requestBody = '{
                  "name": "bob kris project 2",
                  "projectId": "bk-project-290016"
                }';

$response = $service->projects->create($requestBody);

// TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";

die;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a Google internal issue. I recreated your scenario and have the same result. I contacted a Cloud App Engine engineering team and redirected your request. Also, we have already opened a [public ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/168223571), and all communication with Google will continue there.